# API cookie problems - trying to create XSRF/CSRF token in angular

Tags: angularjs, cookies, csrf

My Web API method for initializing a session is successfully returning a cookie.  The front end is in angular so I'm calling the cookie XSRF-TOKEN because angular says it will take that and turn it into a header called X-XSRF-TOKEN in all subsequent requests.

For reference the Web API GET controller method that creates the cookie looks like

```
        ...
        HttpResponseMessage resp = new HttpResponseMessage() {
            Content = new JsonContent(results)
        };
        if (results.Token != null) {
            var cookie = new CookieHeaderValue("XSRF-TOKEN", results.Token);
            cookie.Expires = DateTimeOffset.Now.AddDays(365);
            cookie.Domain = Request.RequestUri.Host;
            cookie.Path = "/";
            cookie.HttpOnly = false;
            resp.Headers.AddCookies(new CookieHeaderValue[] { cookie });
        }
        return resp;
        ...
```

Using Fiddler I can see the cookie in the response.  Now I'm expecting 2 things

1. all subsequent API calls to that same domain should include this cookie in the request header
2. Angular should be adding the X-XSRF-TOKEN header I mentioned earlier

Neither one is happening (I'm checking with Fiddler).  I've tried with the site and API in the same domain (like localhost) and in different domains.

Some sources I've checked:

- https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http
- https://stormpath.com/blog/angular-xsrf

I also tried adding

```
$httpProvider.xsrfWhitelistedOrigins = [webServicesPath];
```

where webServicesPath is a variable I use for the API path but it makes no difference.

Comment: Might be a cross origin issue whereby you need to set `withCredentials` in request

Comment: I found that this works when I run the site using https but not when using http.

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like following

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IAntiforgery antiforgery) {

    context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions() { HttpOnly = false });

}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {

    // Angular's default header name for sending the XSRF token.
    services.AddAntiforgery(options => options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN");    
}
```

Comment: Can you please provide a context for implementing these?